# A couple without a son (in any form) is never freed from the Pitṛ Ṛṇa and becomes a preta?

Tags: rituals, death, sraddha

In this [QnA discussion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/how-do-we-clear-our-debts), we have a remedy for couples who lack a son to clear off their "ancestor debt - "

> Manu Smriti:
>
> 9.127. He who has no son may make his daughter in the following manner an appointed daughter (*putrika*, saying to her husband), ’The (male)
> child, born of her, shall perform my funeral rites.

However, even so then, several couples still will lack any male progeny either in the form of their son or a son from their "appointed daughter", or any "other kind of son". In fact, I personally know of several of these kinds of **specific** couples (living and R.I.P), who are without any male progeny in any line of succession (from son or daughter), and neither did they "appoint" anyone as such for "after-life rituals".

Question -
So from scriptural perspective, what will happen to those couples (without any male in succession)? 
Will they remain as *pretas* forever? Are these **specific** couples never freed from the Pitṛ Ṛṇa ?
What are the scriptural "remedies" for such **specific** "sonless" cases?

---

**Edit:**

Although this QnA - [Aputrasya gatir naasti svargo, naivaca..naivaca](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46295/aputrasya-gatir-naasti-svargo-naivaca-naivaca), does answer some of my questions to a good extent, however, as already discussed above:

The remedies offered in the answer like-
(A): Daughter or Daughter's son doing the rituals.
(B1): Doing a Jeevita Shraddha. This is highly ruled out, since this is extremely frowned upon, at least in my community.
(B2): Adoption is not an option too, atleast for the "specific couples", I talk about.
(B3): We don't have a "king" these days, as a last resort.

So the above list of "options" is ruled out for the **specific couples, I want to discuss.**

Further, "donating a bull" to avoid the *preta yoni* is a good remedy, however, what else besides it?

**Thus, this question is not a duplicate.**

---

So what happens, if the "sonless couples" doesn't follow even those "remedial guidelines" of Garuda Purāṇa, will they always be unclear of their Pitṛ Ṛṇa and roam as *pretas* ?

Comment: Gita 2.42-44, Gita 3.30-31, Gita 6.40, Gita 8.22, 18.64-66. There are more. Take refuge in the Lord. Astvakra Samhita 1.11 - "A man who says he is bound remains bound, a man who says he is free becomes free. This popular saying is true 'As you think so you become'." If you think of ghosts, you shall become one. If you think of God, you will be free.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Ji, so can every Hindu discard these "after-life" rituals and other forms of "samskaras" and just take refuge in the Lord, and be free of all the "ill-sin incurring" consequences, which all the other scriptures speak of?

Comment: What answer do you want?

Comment: Whatever is asked for the "specific case". I just want a scriptural answer to that @Archit

Comment: So basically sonless couples who don’t want either their daughter, son in law, husband’s brothers, friends, Guru to perform, will they still be preta? Am I correct?

Comment: Precisely yes @Archit . I'd further like any reference to remedies (not involving human interventions - like the conjectured peepal tree) to that "specific-situation", if present.

Answer (score 1):

*There are other factors that can affect moksha*

a)[Bhishma Pitamaha’s moksha:Discussed in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16360/23958)

**Pitr rna did not hinder Bhishma’s moksha.**

b)Jaratkaru:

[Refer this for the full incident](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01014.htm)

In the conversation with his ancestors,his ancestors themselves *do not* mention that Jaratkaru will not attain moksha,or become a pret .

They say that fathering a son will be of higher merit than his austerity.

So the incentive for Jaratkaru is **not the possibility of being born in a lower yoni**,but rather the salvation of his ancestors,and higher merit.

3)**The Promise of Sri Krishna**:

[Bhagavad Gita,9.25](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/25)

Sri Krishna’s promise **does not have a condition** that the devotee should not have Pitr shap,so there is some other factor,again.

Comment: Bhishma still had "dedicated *dhArmika*-males" in the family line of succession in the form of Pandavas and the likes. Plus, he actually realized the true nature of Shri Krishna, which is a sure shot door to Moksha, not everyone can have that luxury though. The promise of Shri Krishna is valid. However, there's a difference between "ancestor worship" & "ancestor debt payoff".

Comment: You can edit old answer and flag mods to delete instead of composing new answer

Comment: @Vivikta But even if one didn’t pay off his Pitr rna,if you worships Sri Krishna,then said verse should be applicable to him as well right?

Comment: @Vivikta - Bhishma went to Vasu loka. Not everyone attained Moksha.